# Use ContourPlot3D with an equality stored in a variable?

Tags: plotting

Simply put, I'm trying to use `ContourPlot3D` with an equation stored in a variable. For example:

```
foo=x^2+y^2+z^2==r^2 (* of course, x, y, and z are unassigned, but r is *)
ContourPlot3D[foo, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any way to rectify this?

Comment: try `ContourPlot3D[
 Evaluate@foo, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}]`?

Comment: @kglr yep that's it. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Yet to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = 50;
foo = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r^2; 

ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@foo, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}]
```

[image]